# How can my users delete a file that they uploaded using latest Django version?

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I'm not getting an error message---but when the Delete button is pressed in my template, nothing happens. Does anyone see what's missing in my code below?

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/home/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 
             'home/')
```

models.py

```
class Roll(models.Model):
    csv = models.FileField(default="", upload_to='home/')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.csv.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class DeleteRollView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Roll
    form_class = RollForm
    template_name = 'users/delete_roll.html'

    @staticmethod
    def delete_roll(self, request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            roll = Roll.objects.get(pk=pk)
            roll.delete()
        return redirect('users:list_roll')
```

delete_roll.html

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
```

Comment: First - ensure your input is in the form with action pointing to you delete url. Second - if you are using CBVs - write a `post` method in it, not `delete_roll`, and put your logic there. Also, it should not be static.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Som-1. Per your guidance, I posted my revised post method above in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Revised CBV method, per Som-1's suggestion :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        roll =   
        Roll.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        roll.delete()
    return redirect('users:list_roll')
```